# Joining a csv table to the attribute table of a feature class in arc gis 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, csv

I am new to arcpy. I was trying to join a csv table to the attribute table of a feature class. Here I would like to share what i was trying to do.

```
import arcpy, csv

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"F:\Users\User\Hydrology\Test.gdb"

fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")  
for fc in fcl:

 print "Joining table to " + fc

HRU06 = "F:\Users\User\River\HRU06.csv" 

HRU08 = "F:\Users\User\River\HRU08.csv"

HRU10 = "F:\Users\User\River\HRU10.csv"

HRU12 = "F:\Users\User\River\HRU12.csv"

arcpy.JoinField_management("catchments_03", "FID", HRU06, "HRU_06_FID")
arcpy.JoinField_management("catchments_04", "FID", HRUC08, "HRU_08_FID")
arcpy.JoinField_management("catchments_05", "FID", HRU10, "HRU_10_FID")
arcpy.JoinField_management("catchments_06", "FID", HRU12, "HRU_12_FID")
```

But I am not getting it done. Can someone please help me? I want to join the csv files on the basis of "FID" field of the catchments.

Comment: Do you have column names in your csv? You could also try to add the csv to your map to see if they are read correctly. May be you can show us a few lines of your csv? May be you want to use schema.ini files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What error message do you get? I tried with a csv and found out it can't be joined with arcpy.JoinField_management but i can manually join the Table through the GUI, if you do a right click in the Table of contents and choose Joins and Relates. arcpy.JoinField_management gives me the error 000339: Input test.csv does not have OIDs Failed to execute (JoinField).

Comment: Yes Andreas.....I can do it manually but i wanted to explore other chances so that I can avoid the manual task...

Answer (score 4):

The problem may be with the way you are referencing the CSV file and how python interprets a slash symbol.  You have:

```
HRU06 = "F:\Users\User\River\HRU06.csv"
```

It should be:

```
HRU06 = r"F:\Users\User\River\HRU06.csv"
```

Python should then interpret the text as raw text and it should work, assuming the comments above are valid.

*As a side note you should always report in your question which version of ArcMap/License level you are using and the actual error message, neither of which you have supplied...*